# Merging CSV files with a single column into one CSV file with 14 columns

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I currently have 14 CSV files, each containing one column of data for a day (14 because it goes back 2 weeks)

What I want to do is make one CSV file containing the data from all 14 of these CSVs

eg. if each CSV contains this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I would want the outcome to be a csv file with

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
```

( the actual CSVs have 288 Rows)

I'm currently using some code I found in another question, it worked fine for 2 or 3 CSVs but when I added more it didn't do it for more than the first 3 and the code now looks extremely messy.

Apologies for the large chunk of code, but this is what I have so far.

```
def csvappend():
    with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result1.csv', 'rb') as csv1:
        with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result2.csv', 'rb') as csv2:
            with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result3.csv', 'rb') as csv3:
                with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result4.csv', 'rb') as csv4:
                    with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result5.csv', 'rb') as csv5:
                        with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result6.csv', 'rb') as csv6:
                            with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result7.csv', 'rb') as csv7:
                                with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result8.csv', 'rb') as csv8:
                                    with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result9.csv', 'rb') as csv9:
                                        with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result10.csv', 'rb') as csv10:
                                            with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result11.csv', 'rb') as csv11:
                                                with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result12.csv', 'rb') as csv12:
                                                     with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result13.csv', 'rb') as csv13:
                                                        with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\\result14.csv', 'rb') as csv14:

                                                            reader1 = csv.reader(csv1, delimiter=',')
                                                             reader2 = csv.reader(csv2, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader3 = csv.reader(csv3, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader4 = csv.reader(csv4, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader5 = csv.reader(csv5, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader6 = csv.reader(csv6, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader7 = csv.reader(csv7, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader8 = csv.reader(csv8, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader9 = csv.reader(csv9, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader10 = csv.reader(csv10, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader11 = csv.reader(csv11, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader12 = csv.reader(csv12, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader13 = csv.reader(csv13, delimiter=',')
                                                        reader14 = csv.reader(csv14, delimiter=',')

                                                        all = []
                                                        for row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, \
                                                            row10, row11, row12, row13, row14 in zip(reader1, \
                                                                                                     reader2, reader3,\
                                                                                                     reader4, reader5, \
                                                                                                     reader7, reader8,\
                                                                                                     reader9, reader10, \
                                                                                                     reader11, reader12,\
                                                                                                     reader13,reader14):
                                                            row14.append(row1[0])
                                                            row14.append(row2[0])
                                                            row14.append(row3[0])
                                                            row14.append(row4[0])
                                                            row14.append(row5[0])
                                                            row14.append(row6[0])
                                                            row14.append(row7[0])
                                                            row14.append(row8[0])
                                                            row14.append(row9[0])
                                                            row14.append(row10[0])
                                                            row14.append(row11[0])
                                                            row14.append(row12[0])
                                                            row14.append(row13[0])
                                                            all.append(row14)

            with open('C:\dev\OTQtxt\TODAY.csv', 'wb') as output:
                writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
                writer.writerows(all)
```

I think some of my indenting has been messed up when copying it in, but you should get the idea. And I don't expect to read through all of that, it's very repetitive.

I have seen a few similar/related questions recommending `unix` tools. In case anybody was going to suggest that I'd better tell you this will be running on windows.

If anybody has any ideas of how I could clean this up and actually get it working. I'd be hugely grateful!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement
there is a variation of `with`:  `with A() as a, B() as b ..`, this can kill those indents. And put all your csv* in some kind of list and iterate over them

Comment: Okay, so I can use that `with` variation to clean things up. Would you mind giving an example of the iteration. I can't work out what to actually do after `for csv in csv_list:`

Comment: something like this http://pastebin.com/LdH5NdiR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating files:

```
xxxx@xxxx:/tmp/files$ for i in {1..15}; do echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4" > "my_csv_$i.csv"; done
xxxx@xxxx:/tmp/files$ more my_csv_1.csv 
1
2
3
4
xxxx@xxxx:/tmp/files$ ls
my_csv_10.csv  my_csv_11.csv  my_csv_12.csv  my_csv_13.csv  my_csv_14.csv  my_csv_15.csv  my_csv_1.csv  my_csv_2.csv  my_csv_3.csv  my_csv_4.csv  my_csv_5.csv  my_csv_6.csv  my_csv_7.csv  my_csv_8.csv  my_csv_9.csv
```

Using `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
  with open('result.csv', 'w') as f_obj:
     rows = []
     files = os.listdir('.')
     for f in files:
      rows.append(open(f).readlines())
     iter = izip_longest(*rows)
     for row in iter:
      f_obj.write(','.join([field.strip() for field in row if field is not None])+'\n')
```

Output:

```
xxxxx@xxxx:/tmp/files$ more result.csv 
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
```

That's not the best solution since you will put all your data in memory. But you should get an idea how to do this. By the way if all your data is numeric, I would stays with `numpy` and play with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: The files (when this is finished) will be generated automatically and have the date as the filename. (appended with .csv) will this still work no matter what the name of the CSVs are?

Comment: As you can see, I didn't explicitly specify file names

Comment: This seems like an extremely clean solution! I'll give it a go and see what happens!

Comment: A slightly weird outcome. The script works great, and very fast. However it's reading itself as one of the files to append. So I'm getting rows with code from the script itself in.

Comment: That's not weird but exactly what `os.listdir('.')` does. You should not use it since you never know which files else are going to end up in this folder. It's better to write a function which generates the filenames.

Comment: @a_guest this is what I thought. However the files here will actually be generated from another script. So I do know what will end up here. But as a sort of failsafe (in case someone does put something weird in this folder) I have added `if f.endswith(open(f).readlines())` after the `for` statement

Comment: I don't see what benefit you have from adding this line. I doubt it gives you the expected output. Could you explain what this should do? And even if you 'control' what goes to this folder it is no good style just to take every file in a certain folder. For example `os.listdir('.')` includes the `result.csv` file itself (though it is empty this is unnecessary and you give away control). It is better to specify the files you want to parse. Since the files are generated accordingly to the current date you can easily use a function to generate the list of names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, the files' names can also be specified in a loop:

```
import numpy as np

filenames = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']  # all the files to be read in
data = []  # saves data from the files
for filename in filenames:
    data.append(open(filename, 'r').readlines())  # append a list of all numbers in the current file
data = np.matrix(data).T  # transpose the list of list using numpy

data_string = '\n'.join([','.join([k.strip() for k in j]) for j in data.tolist()])  # create a string by separating inner elements by ',' and outer list by '\n'

with open('newfile', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(data_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have just tested:

```
import csv
import glob

files = glob.glob1("C:\\dev\\OTQtxt", "*csv")

rows=[]

with open('C:\\dev\\OTQtxt\\one.csv', 'a') as oneFile:
    for file in files:
        rows.append(open("C:\\dev\\OTQtxt\\" + file, 'r').read().splitlines())
    for row in rows:
        writer = csv.writer(oneFile)        
        writer.writerow(''.join(row))
```

This will result a file `one.csv` in your directory with csv's that will contain all merdged *csv files

Comment: Apart from the fact that this gives not the desired output it is not good to use something like `files = *.csv in this folder`. What if you run the script, then you update the single .csv files and you run the script again? `one.csv` will be included and also appended to itself. And what if the next week goes also in this folder? You should specify the names of the files you want to parse rather than just taking everything in a folder.